# Meteor spacebars nested {{each}} helper issue

Tags: templates, meteor, each, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have 2 collections: `TestPlans` and `Users`
`TestPlans` has an array called "assigned" which contains `user _ids`.
`Users` has an `avatarUrl` string

I need to iterate over each `testPlan` and furthermore each `assignedUser` and grab an `avatarUrl` for that user:

Something like `{{#each testPlan}} {{#each assignedUser}} {{avatarUrl}}`

the helper for `testPlans` I have:

```
testPlan: function() {
  var testPlans = TestPlans.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch();
  return testPlans;
}
```

the helper for `assignedUser` I have:

```
assignedUser: function(){
 var assignedUsers = TestPlans.findOne({_id: this._id}).assigned;
 return assignedUsers;
}
```

I'm not sure how call the `avatarUrl` for each `assignedUser` though.
The query would be

```
Users.findOne({_id: thisUserId}).profile.avatarUrl;
```

Just not sure how to pass the userid exactly.

Comment: Look into `each...in`: http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in

Answer (score 0):

if assignedUsers is an array of userIds, which might be the best implementation in this case..

```
//html
{{#each testPlan}} 
   {{#each assignedUser}}
     {{profile.avatarUrl}}
     //you can do this because {{this}} is the user object
     //{{profile.avatarUrl}} is the same as {{this.profile.avatarUrl}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}

//js
assignedUser: function(){
   var assignedUsers = TestPlans.findOne({_id: this._id}).assigned;
   var usersCursor = Users.find({_id:{$in:assignedUsers}}});
   return usersCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your assignedUser template helper to accept a user ID parameter and then return the Avatar URL

```
assignedUser: function(userId) {
  return Users.findOne({_id: userId}).profile.avatarUrl
};
```

Then your template code would look something like this.

```
{{#each tp in testPlan}}
  {{#each au in tp.assignedUser}} 
    {{avatarUrl au._id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Also, I like to use `each...in` instead of just `each` because it makes it more explicit what is actually happening